# Can you view running cloud run instances

Tags: google-cloud-run

Is there a way to view how many instances are actually running in cloud run? I can only find min and max instance values.

Comment: Are you using Cloud run fully managed or cloud tun for anthos?

Comment: On fully manage, you don't have more. You can sink the logs into BigQuery and perform a request to know how many difference instance ID are up  over a period of time.